# How can I tell vim to ignore spelling errors inside quotes?

Tags: spell-checking, custom-text-object, dictionary

If I'm editing a text file with `:set spell`, is there any way to 
have vim not check words within the boundaries of certain characters against the word list? I want to be able to write things like proper nouns or technical vocabulary (or even 'sic' quotations) but not have to add them to the wordlist.

Comment: I think this needs proper syntax support.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I take it to mean this is not possible then ? Or, at least not with what capacity vim has already for handling (highlighting, indentation, etc.) different syntax ?

Comment: What Christian means is that you can do it, but only through the `@nospell` keyword in syntax highlight files (see `:help syn-spell`). What kind of file are you editing? Does it already have existing syntax highlighting?

Answer (score 5):

You can add your own syntax element (probably overriding existing one):

```
syntax match quoteblock /"[^"]\+"/ contains=@NoSpell
```

- `syntax match`: Tells vim this is a syntax command
- `quoteblock`: The name of our match (Could be anything)
- `/"..."/`: Match things between quotes
- `[^"]\+`: Match anything that's not a quote
- `contains=@NoSpell`: Tells vim not to use spell check on this match

It is just an example and not very smart :). In my case it stops checking spelling inside quotes:

[image]

- [`:help :syn-spell`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#%3Asyn-spell)
- [`:help spell-syntax`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/spell.txt.html#spell-syntax)
- [`:help :syn-match`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#%3Asyn-match)
- [`:help /collection`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2Fcollection)

**UPD**

You can add to your vimrc the mapping such as:

```
nnoremap <leader>s :syntax match quoteblock /"[^"]\+"/ contains=@NoSpell<CR>
```

Then press `<leader>s` (you know what `<leader>` is right?) to add this syntax element to the current buffer.

Another option is to add a command:

```
command! TurnOffSpellcheckForQuotes :syntax match quoteblock /"[^"]\+"/ contains=@NoSpell
```

Then just run this command from vim `:TurnOffSpellcheckForQuotes`

Comment: Do I just put this into my rc file then ?

Comment: Yes, this should work in your vimrc.

Comment: @myc3lium make sure it works for your files (text? c++? latex? markdown?) -- open your file and enter the command from the answer `:syntax...`.  Then if it works it would be better to create an `autocommand` that will source `:syntax..` for you specific filetypes. And this should be in your vimrc

Comment: You can also enable it upon opening each file by putting `:au Syntax * :syntax match …` in your vimrc, provided that you did `:syntax enable` before that.

Answer (score 1):

If your file already have a syntax highlight, such as `vim`. You can do it like this:

**Preparation**

Add following function and command to your vimrc:

```
function! s:synstack()
  if !exists('*synstack') | return | endif
  return map(synstack(line('.'), col('.')), 'synIDattr(v:val, "name")')
endfunc
command! Synstack echo s:synstack()
```

Assume current file content like this:

```
function! Foo()
  return "balabala"
endfunction
```

**Get Syntax name**

place your cursor at `balabala`, execute `:Synstack`, output is:

```
['vimFuncBody', 'vimString']
```

It's stack of current syntax, from outside function to current string. `vimString` is syntax name of string in `vim`.

**Get Syntax definition**

```
syntax list vimString
```

```
--- Syntax items ---
vimString      xxx start=/[^a-zA-Z>!\\@]"/ms=s+1,lc=1 skip=/\\\\\|\\"/ matchgroup=vimStringEnd end=/"/  oneline keepend contains=@vimStringGroup 
                   start=/[^a-zA-Z>!\\@]'/ms=s+1,lc=1 end=/'/  oneline keepend 
                   start=/=!/ms=s+1,lc=1 skip=/\\\\\|\\!/ end=/!/  oneline contains=@vimStringGroup 
                   start=/=+/ms=s+1,lc=1 skip=/\\\\\|\\+/ end=/+/  oneline contains=@vimStringGroup 
                   start=+\s/\s*\A+ms=s+1,lc=1 skip=/\\\\\|\\+/ end=+/+  oneline contains=@vimStringGroup 
                   match /"[^"]*\\$/  contained nextgroup=vimStringCont skipnl 
                   match /[^(,]'[^']\{-}\zs'/  
                   start=/^\s*\\\z(['"]\)/ skip=/\\\\\|\\\z1/ end=/\z1/  oneline keepend contains=@vimStringGroup,vimContinue 
                   links to String
```

I don't understand above output, the only thing matters is `contains=@vimStringGroup`. So this syntax contains a cluster called `vimStringGroup`

**Add NoSpell to cluster**

```
syntax cluster vimStringGroup add=@NoSpell
```

Done.

- `:h :syn-contain`
- `:h :syn-cluster`
- `:h :spell-syntax`